# When my file is large my writer is null before I close the file

Tags: c#, .net, synchronization, backgroundworker

I have an engine class that responsible to play streaming bytes with my `Player` class and write the bytes to file with my `StreamWriter` class.

I can have more than one engine and more than one players/writers.

Everything works fine until I need to close the file. when I say close I mean to add wave header and do some operation and then I dispose the writer and open a new writer to write the bytes.

My problem is that when the file is small its ok but when the file is larger (a few Mb) then the writer is null before I close the file. How can I avoid this?

Some code:
`Engine` class

```
AddBytesAndSave(byte,[] stream)
{
    writer.AddAndSave(stream);

    // here i think i must wait untill the operation complete
    writer.Dispose;
    writer = null;
}
```

`Writer` class

```
AddAndSave(byte[] stream)
{
    writrToFileWorker.RunWorkerAsync(stream);
}
```

Comment: You are using Backgroundworker (DoWork handler) to handle the async operation.. right?

Comment: yes. but i understand now that wrong way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously, or? When the Array is larger, it takes more time to physically write, and as you do not wait - well...

Technically the Problem is that it makes - from your code - ZERO SENSE to run the write async. Totally None. No real advice needed - any refactoring depends on circumstances we do not know from your code snippet. Just - if the write is asyn, then obviously the writer should not be closed in the AddBytesAndSave method.

Answer (score 1):

You have triggered the asynchronous call. The RunWorkerAsync method submits a request to start the operation running asynchronously. So, your writer is disposed/null before it finished.

Can do like this ,

```
   private void writrToFileWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
  {
      // code to add (after the asynchronous call is completed)
       writer.Dispose;
       writer = null;         
  }
```